# How would I code a tile-matching game onto a page in a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to StackOverflow and to Ruby on Rails. I have made some very basic sites but I am trying to work on a Rails application that features a tile game, where you must select certain tiles in a correct order otherwise it restarts. I need help figuring out how to go about it in general because I am unsure if it would be possible to do it with the Rails app out of the box or if I need gems that would allow me to do it strictly with Ruby. I have done some research and it seems that most likely I will need to do the game logic with Ruby and then script it with JavaScript but I am unsure where to begin. I would love it if some experience Rails developers could help me out.

Comment: Your guess is correct in that you would need a lot of JavaScript. However, if you would also like to store information about games (e.g. allow the user to 'save' the game), you might need a database (that's where you would really need to learn Rails).

My recommendation is that you first write some basic HTML + JavaScript for game. Checkout jQuery, which is a very popular JS library that let's you manipulate HTML pages easily. You could use jQuery to click, drag, and change color of boxes. That would be a great start.

Comment: Rails [being a typical CRUD managing framework] is the worst candidate for the backend for this particular task the man could think of. It’s bloated, full of basecamp-business-specific stuff and is an absolute outlier for the game production. If you want to go with Ruby, you should check [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) or like minimalistic framework to accomplish what the server in games usually does: to provide a robust API for the frontend. Frontend is, yes, usually being written in javascript.